# Plot 3D graphs in R-studio

Tags: r, graph

Sorry for the question, but I have a variable that I would like to plot like this: 
[image]

I am a newby on R, so I am having some difficulties. I appreciate any kind of help. 
Thanks!

Comment: there are several packages, did you try googling the title of this question?

Comment: Have you tried to make a surface plot using the `plotly` package?
https://plot.ly/r/3d-surface-plots/

Answer (score 1):

Since you're looking to plot what appears to be a 3d surface, I'd suggest starting with the `persp` function, from the `graphics` package. This blog post (http://www.r-bloggers.com/3d-plots-in-r/) gives a good treatment of several options for 3D plotting:

> the generic function persp() in the base graphics package draws perspective plots of a surface over the x–y plane. Typing demo(persp) at the console will give you an idea of what this function can do.

And running `demo(persp)` gives you a number of examples, including this one:

[image]

There are also some more suggestions for going further:

> The plot3D package from Karline Soetaert builds on on persp()to provide functions for both 2D and 3D plotting. [...] Load the package and type the following commands at the console: example(persp3D), example(surf3D) and example(scatter3D) to see examples of 3D surface and scatter plots.

As a side note, @rawr's comment is spot on - I found all this in less than a minute, using two google searches - one of which was the title of your post. I'm putting this answer up anyway, since StackOverflow posts frequently *become* the top google result for many topics. But the best advice I can give you going forward is that R is one of the most aggressively well-documented languages out there, both in terms of formal and informal documentation, and you can find a lot just by googling what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks! I try this scatterplot3d(Y, X, Z, main= "Runoff", pch=20, type="h") Although I don't get the image that I need..I get several points, but not the surface image type that I need,

Comment: @Leonor In general, you've got a much better shot at getting the help you need if you include in your question a minimum reproducible example (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) showing what you've already tried to do to solve the problem, and being specific about what the problem you're trying to solve is. As it stands, I can only give you my best guess - it looks like you're using a function designed to create scatterplots, and you're getting a scatterplot as a result.